# Jquery datepicker icon hide

Tags: jquery

I am using a Jquery dialog for both viewing a record and editing a record. When in edit mode the user can change the date using the datepicker. In viewmode I need to hide the datepicker icon and only show the date. Is there a way to toggle the datepicker icon on and off as needed?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the datepicker has no icon. The datepicker shows up if you hover the date input field. Likely the icon is from the original site, so you want to remove it from the html or hide it through css.
You may want to add an ID or a class in edit mode and attach the datepicker to that.
The full correct answer depends a bit on the actual application ;)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `createButton: false` as an option.